# jQuery convert text into inputfields

Tags: jquery

On my page i have a couple of tags that looks like this:

```
<parameter name="address" class="transform">@ViewBag.Address</parameter>
```

To do that i have created this function:

```
 function transform(id) {
     $('#' + id + ' .transform').each(function (index) {
         var tag = $(this).parent().html();
         $(this).parent().html() = tag.replace('parameter','input type="text"');
     });
 }
```

Now, if i alert $(this).parent().html() i get the original tag, but the function doesn't work. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `$(this).parent().html() = "value"` call is wrong. Have a look to example in the API http://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: No, the selector says that it should loop through every DOM-element with the class 'transform' within the element (in singular) with the specified ID.

Comment: @AntonGildebrand - Since I was unable to get the answer you chose to work, I created a solution with a jsFiddle (see below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one (give html function a parameter, may be the cause of the problem

```
function transform(id) {
 $('#' + id + ' .transform').each(function (index) {
     var tag = $(this).parent().html();
     $(this).parent().html( tag.replace('parameter','input type="text"') );
 });
 }
```

Comment: Thank you! I guess i got a little confused.

Comment: Hmmm, this didn't work for me when I created a fiddle to test it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer you accepted didn't work for me so I created this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/f68qA/)**.

jQuery:

```
function transform(id) {
    $('#' + id + ' .transform').each(function(index) {
        $(this).replaceWith($('<input value="' + $(this).html() + '" type="text" name="address" class="transform" />'));
    });
}
```

This will convert the parameter tags into input elements and place the @ViewBag.Address text as the default value for each input.